# JavaFX - TreeView - CSS doesn't apply when selecting element programmatically

Tags: css, javafx, treeview, selected

(Reposted with complete information, an example and a video)

I have a working TreeView in JavaFX 8 with two levels. I want to expand the first level and select a TreeItem from the second level. To select an item, I currently use:

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().setSelectedItem(itemToSelect)
```

This works perfectly, because if afterwards I print the

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
```

The printed item is the correct one.

My issue is that this style is not applied to it:

```
.treeView .tree-cell:selected {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-background-color: #993300;
}
```

treeView is the correct style class of the treeView, and when using it normally it works perfectly. In other words: when I select an element with my mouse, it gets bold and the background color changes. When I select an element via code, the CSS isn't applied.

What could I do?

This is the TreeViewSample.java (actually I'm using Groovy but I don't think it matters) class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeViewSample extends Application {

    private final Node rootIcon = new ImageView(
        new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder_16.png"))
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(TreeViewSample,args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");

        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String> ("Inbox", rootIcon);
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String> ("Message" + i);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);

        }
        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String> (rootItem);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(3);
        tree.getStylesheets().add("style.css")
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And this is style.css:

```
.tree-view {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: #993300;
}
.tree-view .tree-cell {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: #ffcc00;
    -fx-font-size: 16;
}
.tree-view .tree-cell:selected {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-background-color: #993300;
}

.tree-view .tree-cell:filled:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #5e1f00;
}

.tree-view .tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow  {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Again, the problem is that the :selected attribute in the CSS doesn't apply when I select the fourth item with the setSelectedIndex method or the setSelectedItem method.

Using JDK 1.8.0_181 on Windows 8.1

[image: This is an example video]

As you can see from the video, the number 3 is printed (that means that the selected element is the number 3) but the fourth element in the treeView is NOT highlighted with a brown background.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the index after `primaryStage.show()`?

Comment: Yes, nothing changes.

Comment: Im using Java 10, but you should be able to do `tree.getSelectionModel().select(3);` instead of `setSelectedIndex(3);`

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the issue. I can't believe I didn't notice that method!